# Import default react component with two or more different name

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

**What I am trying to do:**
Import the same default component twice or more times in **one** file. The reason of why I want to do this are because the component are the same, I only need the name difference to make it more readable.

**What I have done:**
import ToInput from './input';
import FromInput from './input';

Is there a correct way to do this? It works, but the ESLint is complaining about duplicate import.

Answer (score 6):

```
import Input as MyInput from './input';
import Input as MySecondInput from './input';
```

Now you may use the component as MyInput or MySecondInput, as both are references or instances of the same component.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you really want to do is **create two distinct instances** of an `Input` component, but what you have described is to **create a copy of the `Input` component class/descriptor**. While it is possible to do this, it is usually a bad practice.

Try to think about React in terms of ***Object Oriented*** concepts. Remember that the imported construct from './input' (in your case, `ToInput`) is a **Class** and not yet an **Instance** of that class.

Traditionally to create an instance of a class called `Input`, we would write something like this:

```
var toInput = new Input()
```

However, when defining an instance of the class `Input` in React, we typically use **JSX** tags:

```
<Input />
```

The above is JSX tag is **an instance of** `Input`, and **NOT** actually the `Input` class itself.

From what I gather in your question, I think the following would be a more appropriate approach that employs better patterns and practices.

Import a singular, generic `Input` component descriptor/class.

```
import Input from './input'
```

If **readability is your ultimate goal**, then perhaps differentiate the two components with a **prop**, rather than creating copies of the component class. You could use an `id` prop for example:

```
<Input id='to-input' />
<Input id='from-input' />
```

Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: `<Input />` does not return an instance of `Input` FYI, it returns an object that React can use to create an instance if it doesn't already have one.

Comment: My bad - any recommendations on how to re-word my answer? @loganfsmyth

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't ever need to do this. Post the scenario as to why you need this.

Just do this:

`const FromInput = ToInput;`

Or just disable the eslint rule for that file if you really need it.

`/* eslint-disable import/your-rule-here */`

Comment: Thank you very much! Why did I not think of that myself?
Can you be more specific on why I should not do this?

Comment: @ReidunMarie Because you already have the imported value. Importing it again into another variable makes no sense as you can just assign the imported variable to a var instead like in my answer. I think also there is the potential to import the file twice if caching is turned off for some reason (it should be on by default) this is probably also why you are getting the eslint error.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!